# How to get button text in vue-test-utils

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

How do I retrieve the button text from a found element in `vue-test-utils`? I am using v1.0.0-beta.10

For example, in my vue file I have a button like:

```
el-button(@click.native="cancel",
          size="small",
          native-type="button") Cancel
```

Then in my tests:

```
const button = wrapper.findAll({
  name: "el-button"
})

console.log('buttonAll is', button.at(2).vnode.$attrs) // {}
```

I get an empty object. Even better, how can I directly query that Vue component based on button text?

Answer (score 9):

You can retrieve the button text from a found element like this:

```
 describe('Button', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(VueComponent);
  });
  it('has a button with text mazino', () => {
    let button = wrapper.find('.mazino');
    expect(button.text()).toBe('mazino');
  });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that just a class selector? I get an error where `button` equals `ErrorWrapper { selector: '.Cancel' }`

Comment: Yeah it is a class selector, and it works. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I don't have an error thrown, but I am unable to find a button that I can use. You can see above I reference that it is an `ErrorWrapper`, so I can't do anything with it. Ideally I'd like to trigger a `click` event.

Comment: If I call `text()` on it I will get this error: `Error: [vue-test-utils]: cannot call wrapper.text() on a wrapper without an element`

Comment: @writofmandamus that means that `find` was unsuccessful. The selector you're using can't be found in the render tree.

Comment: I don't have this setup anymore but I'm guessing it is because el-button isn't actually a native button element (but a custom element wrapping around one).

Comment: let button = wrapper.findAll('.mazino'); Works for me

Comment: THis says "has a button with text mazino", but that's nto what it's doing at all. it's looking for a component that has the class `mazino`.

Comment: @VikashAnand I had the same errorWrapper issue and `findAll()` works for me vs using `find()`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I query buttons by text

```
function findByText (wrap, selector, text) {
  return wrap.findAll(selector).filter(n => n.text().match(text));
}

describe('Button', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(VueComponent);
  });
  it('has a button with text foo', () => {
    const button = findByText(wrapper, 'button', /foo/).at(0);
    expect(button.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```